# AlarmManager doesn't fire after App was closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an Alarm defined with AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver. Everything works great when my App is running. But as soon as I close the App nothing more happens... I read in the references, that the alarm should go although the App is not running.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
I also searched the web but didn't find anything which is about the same as my problem.

Here is my AlarmManager:

```
public void addAlarm(Long time, Integer piID, Boolean start) {


    calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    Log.e("date", String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    String intentstr = CAL_ALERT + String.valueOf(piID);
    Intent intent = new Intent(intentstr);  
    intent.putExtra(AppointmentStart, start);
    Log.d("startkey", String.valueOf((intent.getBooleanExtra("startkey", false))));
    Log.d("endkey", String.valueOf((intent.getBooleanExtra("endkey", false))));
    Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(piID));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), piID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);   
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(intentstr); 
    registerReceiver(new Alarmreceiver(), filter);  
    almanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);    
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Have you defined your broadcast receiver in the manifest?